apt dependency issue for libc6 packages in bookworm
When trying to update a bookworm system, I encountered the following issue:
apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dbg : Depends: libc6 (= 2.36-9+deb12u6) but 2.36-9+deb12u4 is installed
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.36-9+deb12u6) but 2.36-9+deb12u4 is installed
 libc6-i386 : Depends: libc6 (= 2.36-9+deb12u6) but 2.36-9+deb12u4 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).

Trying to resolve this led to:
apt --fix-broken install
(further text omitted)
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 188404 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libc6_2.36-9+deb12u6_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:amd64 (2.36-9+deb12u6) over (2.36-9+deb12u4) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.36-9+deb12u6_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2', which is also in package libc-bin 2.36-9+deb12u4
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libc6_2.36-9+deb12u6_amd64.deb
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Normally I'd remove the file in question, but I'm a little hesitant to remove the dynamic loader of this Debian system as a reinstallation would be imminent due to the fact that no program would be able to start as this dynamic loader is hard-coded in the ELF binaries of executables.
`apt remove libc-bin`

resulted in the same dependency error as described above. Needless to say, this situation prevents me from any upgrade let alone package installation.
Any pointers are appreciated, more than happy to provide additional information as required.

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see which questions are on-topic on this site.
You might want to delete this question and ask it on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ instead, but check the help pages there first.

Turns out the solution is quite simple: for some reason (package corruption?) both packages (libc6 and libc-bin contain symlinks to /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2).
As dpkg checks for the targets of any contained symlinks, simply modifying a package file list (ie. removing this symlink) does the trick. After eliminating the line lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 from /var/lib/dpkg/info/libc-bin.list,  apt --fix-broken install was happy to do its job and a full dist-upgrade could convene.
I suppose this approach applies to similar issues exhibiting the same root cause as well.
